# Is socket.io working with nodejs cluser?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

there are quite some resource for this answer, but to be honest, I have tried all them, and it does not work at all.
Node: 0.10.x
Express: _4.2.0
socket.io: 1.0.6
socket.io-redis: 0.1.3

But whenever I use this one:

```
var app = require('./config/express')(db);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Socket failed working.

Can anyone show me how you make socketio working with express?
I don't want to use this format:
    io = require('xxx')(3000)
as I want express app to listen to 3000 port

Or socketio is not working with cluster at all?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: if we use .listen, we need to use listen(3000), right? otherwise, we just need to bind app like this. Also have you met any problem in using socketio with clusters?

Comment: As soon as I put .listen(app), I am having this error:GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1409778854659-2&sid=lGP7lcq-vYvbIAo5AAAB 
400 Bad Request, but if I use  io = require('socket.io')(server), then everything is fine